# Docker container permission denied on startup

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mysql, docker, amazon-web-services

I have 2 AWS instances with percona cluster running in docker containers.
After someone rebooted one of instances I needed to repair a large amount of things. But I can't restart percona cluster on one instance (owner of swarm). I can't delete cluster and recreate it again because of files included in it. When executing `docker start percona-mysql` container responds with folowing:

```
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled 
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown
```

How I can repair this issue? On second instance cluster starts as intended.

Comment: Was this ever solved? Seems like [this issue is discussed here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/issues/385#issuecomment-619348645) in depth.